# How to set http_proxy for chef remote_file resource

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I am looking for help where I need to download binaries from chef-cookbook from https url and I can not make a direct call to the url from client server.

I am able to download it using curl but after passing proxy server with port.
But I want to use remote_file resource and I am not able to set the proxy for my https url as there is no option with in remote file.

can someone please help me with.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to set the [proxy setting in chef-client configuration](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client/)

> `http_proxy` The proxy server for HTTP connections. Default value: `nil`.
>
> `http_proxy_pass` The password for the proxy server when the proxy server is using an HTTP connection. Default value: `nil`.
>
> `http_proxy_user` The user name for the proxy server when the proxy server is using an HTTP connection. Default value: `nil`.

you might like to leverage [chef-client cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client) to set these settings

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer.
I have tried it manually and it worked so far.But when I am trying to set it via cookbook itself before downloading the files using remote_file resource it is not working.
But when I run the same cookbook again its working file.
Can you help what can be the issue.Below code I am using to set proxy via cookbook:
ruby_block "set https_proxy" do
  block do
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/chef/client.rb")
    file.insert_line_if_no_match("https_proxy","https_proxy 'https://example.com:20080'")
    file.write_file
  end
 end

Comment: if it worked for you, then please make accept my answer. secondly, please create a new question with all the errors and details and i would be happy to assist

Answer (score 0):

ruby_block 'set https_proxy' do
block do
ENV['https_proxy'] = "https://<example.url.com>:20080"
end
end

Above code helped me out to set the https_proxy.